# Quartz job is not updating database

Tags: java, scheduling, quartz-scheduler, crontrigger

I have triggered Quartz job pragmatically. But it's not looking updating the database.
I mean, "**PREV_FIRE_TIME**" column is not getting updated. I have run the following code.

```
stdScheduler.triggerJob(jobName,jobGroupName);
```

Though, during normal schedule execution database is getting updated but if I make an Ad hoc 
run, it's not updating the database. 
Could any one please suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your job getting fired or not? or you mean job is getting fired but not updating the DB

Comment: Yes, job is getting fired properly but DB is not getting updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that your job class is not running under the transaction.
When quartz picks up the job and runs the execute method it is in a different thread.You need to wrap it under transaction. In spring I would have set the transaction advice around the execute method .
Alternarively you can set the below property true in quartz which should do the job for you:

```
org.quartz.scheduler.wrapJobExecutionInUserTransaction=true
```

Comment: @tomasznurkiewicz how to achieve the same in spring 4 with annotation based configuration. Please [see](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41213446/how-to-run-update-query-in-spring-jpa-for-quartz-job) my question